# List assignment/creation in Python showing unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I was playing around with a block of code during which I stumbled upon some unexpected behaviour of Python.

I defined a list as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Made another list with a loop:

```
res = (item for item in a if a.count(item) > 0)
print(list(res)) # [1, 2, 3] -- as expected -- Consider this is line 1
```

Then later I changed the initial value of first list:

```
a = [7, 2, 9]
```

I was expecting no change in `res` as the changes I made to `a` were after `res` was created, but to my surprise, the value of res was changed.

```
print(list(res)) # prints [] -- Consider this as line 2
```

What's more shocking is that the result of print depends on print statement on line 1, if I comment out print statement at line1 then line 2 prints `[2]`

Can someone please explain me what's going on here?

Comment: Variable `x` isn't set anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited.

Comment: Reassigning `a` has nothing to do with it. You'll see the same effect if you simply do `print(list(res))` twice in a row.

Comment: Seriously consider studying python's protocols and generators

Comment: As an aside, `(item for item in a if a.count(item) > 0)` is an inefficient algorithm for this, it is quadratic time when you can do it in linear time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res = (item for item in a if a.count(x) > 0)` creates a generator that is exhausted by calling `list(res)`.

When you call the next `list(res)` it returns empty list - `[]`

consider creating a list first, for example `res = [item for item in a if a.count(x) > 0]`.

Comment: Hey @andrej, It would be really kind of you if you could give my answer a read and post a comment on that if you think its right or wrong.

Comment: @YudhishthirSingh Yes, your answer is OK - the generator can be iterated over only once. There's more info about it for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I get it, I was not creating another list with that loop and I was creating something called generator.

Which can be converted to list only once, that is why it prints [] if I give print statement at line 1.

And it modifies itself according to value of a until it is exhausted.